# Angular 2 - Creating a CSV file from nested Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am trying to create an object for csv file from the nested array which looks something like this -

```
[
  {
    "Name":obj.name,
    "Age": obj.age,
    "Class":obj.class
  }
]
```

I have generated this array using the code which looks something like -

```
let obj = originalObj.map(studentObj => {
   return {
     "Name":studentObj.name,
     "Age":studentObj.age,
     "class":studentObj.class
   }
}
```

Now here the `obj.class` is an object of comma separated values i.e `maths,biology,physics`. The number of classes are not fixed and dynamic, what I mean is a person can have 2 classes or 3 or 4 or can have no class at all. The csv i want to generate should look something like this -

```
| Name | Age | Class     | Class     | Class      |
|------|-----|-----------|-----------|------------|
| abc  | 12  |           |           |            |
| xyz  | 18  | Computers |           |            |
| ijk  | 20  | Astronomy | Geography | Science    |
```

How do I transform the array object to generate the required object which can generate the csv like above? I would preferably not use any external npm library for this unless it is absolutely necessary.

I did tried with the sample code provided below by @Mr. Ratnadeep and it works well if the number of classes are fixed, but in my case the first record don't have a class hence while converting into `csv` keys are not getting generated for the class at all. Need help to solve this challenge I am out of my depth.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON does not contain the multiple keys with same name. Instead of that I have implemented. Implemented using the sample data in original object, you can modify it as per your need.
**Name | Age | class1 | class2 | class3 ...**

used `jsonexport` npm package for creating csv.

```
var myData = [
  {
    "Name":'John',
    "Age": 28,
    "Classes":"Maths,Biology,Physics"
  }
]

for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
    var arrClass = myData[i].Classes.split (',');
    delete myData[i].Classes
    arrClass.forEach(function(ele,index){
        var keyName = 'class'+(index+1);
        myData[i][keyName]= ele;
    });
}
jsonexport(myData,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
    fs.writeFile('test.csv',csv,function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**Output:**
[image]

- **Updated Answer**

I don't have idea how you are generating the csv. But I have prepared the final `myData` array of json objects. The classes columns are dynamic in nature.

```
var myData = [
  {
        "Name":'abc',
        "Age": 12 
    },
    {
        "Name": 'xyz',
        "Age": 18,
        "Classes": "Computers"
    },
    {
        "Name": 'ijk',
        "Age": 20,
        "Classes": "Astronomy,Geography,Science"
    }
]

for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
    if (myData[i].hasOwnProperty("Classes")){
        var arrClass = myData[i].Classes.split(',');
        delete myData[i].Classes;
        arrClass.forEach(function (ele, index) {
            var keyName = 'class' + (index + 1);
            myData[i][keyName] = ele;
        });
    }
}
jsonexport(myData,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
    fs.writeFile('test.csv',csv,function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I have updated the problem statement can you please have a look?

Comment: @jeet I have updated my answer, plz go through it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The expected result is not a valid CSV. You can't have three columns with the same name. But you can keep your obj.class as a csv string. A naive and incomplete implementation could be:

```
function toCSV(items, separator=';') {
  if (!items.length) return '';

  const columns = Object.keys(items[0]).join(separator);
  const body = items.map(item =>
    Object.values(item).join(separator)
  ).join('\n');

  return columns + '\n' + body;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the problem statement can you please have a look?